# Apply a JavaScript function to the parent of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just refreshing my JavaScript/Jquery skills and I thought of making a basic todo app. I've figured out how to create elements with input from the user via a textbox. All these list  elements have a delete task link. I want it such that when a user click on that link it deletes the respective list item.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26335627/Projects/Todo%20App/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
$('.delete-task').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
    // do some other stuff
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.delete-task').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`element.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.parentNode) property.